# Multiple Phrases in one PdfPCell

Tags: java, itext

I want to add multiple Phrase in one PdfPCell.
My concern is, I want to display like 
"Created Date :" in gray font and than "Date" in black font in one cell.

So, is there anyway to do this ? Please help.

Code is like,

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Created Date : ",grayFont));
```

Now, I want to add Date after that without adding new Cell. Is that possible?

Comment: Add a table around both values.

Comment: I don't want to use another cell or table. Because I am doing this in one table in which there are multiple rows and columns.

Comment: Than i thin it is not possible.

Comment: Well you "thought" wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a cell, and add as many `Phrase` as needed :

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(new Phrase("Created Date : ", grayFont));
cell.addElement(new Phrase(theDate, blackFont));
```

You could also consider adding [`Chunk`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html) instead of `Phrase`.

Answer (score 1):

wrap multiple [Phrase](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Phrase.html)s with different fonts in a [Paragraph](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Paragraph.html). Mind you : the Paragraph **will** cause **siblings** (not the content, of course) to wrap as long as you dont wrap them as well

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Phrase datePhrase = new Phrase(new Chunk("Created Date", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.GRAY)));
datePhrase.add(new Phrase(new Chunk("Your Date", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK))));
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(datePhrase);
```

Comment: thanks, good approach, but I would do it like this: datePhrase.add(new Chunk("Your Date", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 16, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));